# Convert long to date in query

Tags: android, sqlite, date, compare

I have saved my date into timestamp format in my database. I wish to retrieve my record on for a specific date (For example only today's record). How do I format the date stored formatted as long in my table? Below is my current code:

```
public static long getTodayRecord(Context context, String recordId) {
    long timeSpan= System.currentTimeMillis();
    String currentDay = DateTimeUtil.getDisplayShortDate(currentTimespan);

    String dateString= DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(currentTimespan)).toString();

    String selection = "COLUMN_RECORD_ID" + " = ? AND date(" + "COLUMN_RECORD_DATE" + ") = ?";

    String[] selectionArg= {recordId, dateString};
    return DbUtil.count(context, "RECORD_TABLE, selection, selectionArgs);
}
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Date date=new Date(val);
 SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 String dateText = df2.format(date);
```

if your date is not in  long format then must convert the string to long

```
long val = Long.parseLong(dateCreated);
```